# what is this error about? wordpress

Tags: wordpress

POST http://www.chavoush.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php 500 (Internal Server Error)

send @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:4
ajax @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:4
n.(anonymous function) @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:4
ajax @ wpProQuiz_front.min.js?ver=3.3:1
sendCompletedQuiz @ wpProQuiz_front.min.js?ver=3.3:1
finishQuiz @ wpProQuiz_front.min.js?ver=3.3:1
(anonymous function) @ wpProQuiz_front.min.js?ver=3.3:1
dispatch @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3
r.handle @ jquery.js?ver=1.12.4:3

Answer (score 0):

**Case 1** : installing the Postman SMTP plugin. Give that a try.

**Case 2** : Check valid address in the ’email from’ field.

I hope,Emails are now be sent out correctly.